# Supabase RLS | How to check the boolen cells?

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I created a policy like this:

```
CREATE POLICY "Users can update the row if card is not opened" ON "public"."pool"
AS PERMISSIVE FOR UPDATE
TO authenticated
USING (pool_item_is_opened = false)
WITH CHECK (pool_item_is_opened = false)
```

`pool_item_is_opened` is boolen cell.

But it gives me Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: PostgrestException(message: new row violates row-level security policy for table "pool", code: 42501, details: Forbidden, hint: null)
```

I'm working on mobile app (Flutter).
Here is the code:

```
final obj = {
      "pool_item_is_opened": true,
      "pool_opened_user_id": supabase.auth.currentUser!.id,
      "pool_item_opened_at": DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
      "chat_id": _createdChat['id'],
    };
final _res = await supabase.from("pool").update(obj).match({"id": cardId});
```

What is wrong in here? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with check` keyword is used to check your data against incoming data. In your example, you are trying to update the `pool_item_is_opened` to `true`, so you need to update the `with check` like this:

```sql
CREATE POLICY "Users can update the row if card is not opened" ON "public"."pool"
AS PERMISSIVE FOR UPDATE
TO authenticated
USING (pool_item_is_opened = false)
WITH CHECK (pool_item_is_opened = true)
```